# Closed form solutions to functions involving Erfc

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Is there a better way to get a closed form solution in terms of `sigma`? I've already attempted a significant amount of simplification up to this point and am unsure how to go on. The below "full simplify" doesn't run on my machine:

```
FullSimplify[
 Log[1/(1 +
     Integrate[(-((-3*K^2 + 6*K + 1^2)/(2*K^(3/2)*(K + 1)^3)))*
       ((1/2)*K*
          Erfc[(-(σ^2/2) + Log[1/K])/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] -
         (1/2)*
          Erfc[(σ^2/2 + Log[1/K])/(Sqrt[2]*σ)]), {K, 0, 1}] +
     Integrate[(-((-3*K^2 + 6*K + 1^2)/(2*K^(3/2)*(K + 1)^3)))*
       ((-(1/2))*K*
          Erfc[-((-(σ^2/2) + Log[1/K])/(Sqrt[2]*σ))] +
         (1/2)*
          Erfc[-((σ^2/2 + Log[1/K])/(Sqrt[2]*σ))]),
      {K, 1, Infinity}])], Assumptions -> {σ > 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/), you can see in detail which parts of your expression seem to not have an analytic solution. For your first integral, one of these parts is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even when stripping the analytic `σ` and reducing the expression, it appears that this similar form has no antiderivative which can be calculated by either Mathematica or with Rubi

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore, I tend to say you'll hit a dead end trying to find an analytic solution to your much more complex expression and you are left with numerics.